# What are all valid ways of writing closures that return nothing and accept no parameters in Objective-C and Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swiftui, closures

I'm having trouble understanding closure syntax in Swift and Objective-C.

Can someone tell me all possible ways in both languages to write a closure which accepts no arguments and returns nothing?

Comment: There aren't really possibilities of closures/blocks that take no parameters and don't return a value. There is exactly one. See zeytin's answer for the Swift and Objective-C syntax of such a closure/block.

Comment: FYI, they’re called [blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html) in Objective-C, and [closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) in Swift.

Comment: FYI, here is a cheat sheet for using blocks in a variety of contexts in Objective-C: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/

Comment: Thanks all links and comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Objective-C language

```objectivec
void (^closureA)(void) = ^{ };
```

In Swift language

```swift
let closureB: () -> ()
        
let closureC: () -> Void
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you ask for **all** and since C is within Objective-C's reach and since you specify no parameters, this also gets the job done.

```
void ( * f ) ( void );       // C function pointer
```

Above is purely academic and below for amusement, but with that you can do the following!

```
        // Void block to void function pointer
        void ( ^ block ) ( void ) = ^ {
            NSLog ( @"You have been warned" );
        };

        void * p = & block;
        long * q = ( long * )( * ( long * ) p );
        long * r = q + 2; // Try 0, 1, 2 [crash crash voila!]

        void ( * f ) ( void ) = ( void ( * )( void ) )( * r );

        // You have been warned
        f ();
```

This is extremely dangerous (and entertaining) but does illustrate the equivalence between the void block and function pointer.