# Closures(Swift) to closures(blocks?) in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, closures, objective-c-blocks

Hi guys Im kinda new to Objective-C and I've got a little code that I would like to convert it from Swift -> Objective-C. I've got a variable which is a closures but not sure how doing it in Objective-C
Here's the variable:

```
var didTimerFire: ((UICollectionViewCell) -> Void)?
```

also is there's any "self" in objective-C? sorry for being a noob but again kinda new to Objective-C :)

Comment: you can also check out my answer comparing the closures and blocks syntax https://stackoverflow.com/a/64615010/14531220

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C there are `Blocks`:

If you want to use them as property it goes like:

`@property (nonatomic, copy, nullability) returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes);`

Or as method parameters:

`- (void)method:(returnType (^nullability)(parameterTypes))blockName;`

So for you example it will go like:

`@property (nonatomic, copy, nullable) void (^didTimerFire)(UICollectionViewCell);`

Comment: Got ya :) btw is there any "Self" in Objective-C as Swift has? :)

Comment: I have written a LOT of Objective-C, and I never did memorize the hideous block syntax. The way you specify a property, a method parameter, and a block type are all different and non-intuitive. There is a link I bookmarked called http://fuckingblocksyntax.com. I suggest referring to that.

Comment: @Grzegorz Krukowski btw how to use it like this in objective-c : cell.didTimerFire = { [weak self] cell in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.impressionEventStalker?.stalkCells()
        } like completion handler

Comment: I seem to remember there being a G rated version of the page with exactly the same content. I hesitated to link it, given the off-color name, but it certainly captures my (and others', obviously) feelings about Objective-C block syntax.